# .htaccess Rules Are Not Implemented

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

On amazon ec2 I've created a .htaccess file with the following rules :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301] 


<Files /index.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

But I still can directly access /index.php file and the first rule is not implemented as well.
First the file was located in the `/www` folder , once it didn't work I've moved it to `/www/html` , but it still does not seem to work properly.

I'd like to know how to solve this issue, thanks.

Comment: For the .htaccess to be parsed, you need at least an `AllowOverride` directive in the VirtualHost config. For the `Allow from` to work, you need `AllowOverride AuthConfig` http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride Use `AllowOverride All` in the VirtualHost if you plan to manage all of this from .htaccess.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Files` you can use `RewriteRule` to block it:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301] 

RewriteRule (^|/)index\.php(/|$) - [F,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks , but it's not the point.I'm not looking for .htaccess imporvements,  i'm trying to get it work first.

Comment: That's precisely the reason why I suggested this rule to **make it work** If it is not working then let me know for which URL it didn't work.

Comment: I've also added the line "INVALID LINE" to the .htaccess file in order to check if it is being parsed , got no error so it seems like it's not being parsed

Comment: You mean your original rule in question to remove `.html` isn't working either?

Comment: The original first rule and the second rule you've offered does not work

Comment: ok then you need to enable .htaccess and mod_rewrite via your Apache config first.

Comment: I've enabled .htaccess in the httpd.config file by using     AllowOverride All.

Comment: Well then make your suggested rule in question work. If that rule starts working then my answer will also be workable.